# How can search through json data in vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a json file with I render to table , I have 11 columns like a id , name and etc , I would like to search by every column, but its work for one column and when I start to filtered data one more time for instance I have sort by id  and after that I want to sort by name , it crashed.

I have v-for structure for render data from json

```html
<div class="document__json" v-for="(item,index) in filteredJson" :key="index" >
  <div class="document__data" :title=item.priority>{{item.priority}}</div>
  <div class="document__data" :title=item.refid_number>{{item.refid_number}}</div>
</div>
```

I try to search through json using v-model , every letter / word i send to array

```
data() {
  return {
    myJson: json,
    search: []
  };
},

filteredJson: function() {
  let new_json;
  return this.myJson.filter((x) => {
    new_json = x;
    console.log(x);
    for (let i in this.search) {
      console.log(new_json[i])
      console.log(this.search)
      new_json = new_json[i].toLowerCase().match(this.search[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    return new_json
  });
}

<input type="text" v-model="search['priority']" class="document_search">
<input type="text" v-model="search['refid_number']" class="document_search">
```

I try to filter json by compare with data inside search array , but it work if I will search by priority only if I will try to search also by refid_number it fill crush  with error:
  `Cannot read property 'refid_number' of null"`

Comment: I think you need a new variable for filter. Because when you filter data in `myJson` variable, data will not exists in that variable. Try to create `let jsonForFilter = this.myJson` and filter through ` jsonForFilter`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your filter function, first you set `new_json = x` (which is an object), but then inside the for loop you set `new_json` to be a `match` result, which would be an array, and it would not have the members as the original object (`x`), so it would crash on the next loop.

I'm guessing that what you need is something like this:

```
return this.myJson.filter((x) => {
    let match = true;
    console.log(x);
    for(let i in this.search){
        console.log(x[i])
        console.log(this.search)
        if(!x[i].toLowerCase().match(this.search[i].toLowerCase())) match = false;
    }
    return match;
});
```

Comment: but can u describe   a little  if(!x[i].toLowerCase().match(this.search[i].toLowerCase())) match = false; this one , how did you come for this ? And what is more , how it is work ?

Comment: Sure. Like I said, the `match` method returns an array when the matching is successful, otherwise it returns `null` . By placing `!` in front of it, it will force the result to convert to the opposite boolean value, so an array becomes `false`, and `null` becomes `true`. So basically, the condition inside `if` translates to "if the matching fails".

Comment: But you define let match  = true - it means all data is here ?  in due to when you return match u also return data , can`t understand this one

Comment: also have a lot of errors in due to i can use lowercase or to string with null or object , i have tryed to cover it with other div but also doest`not work

Comment: The variable `match` (sorry for the name choice; it might be confusing) here is for telling "if the matching is still successful". If any column fails to match, I set `match = false` to track this fact. At the end, `match` is returned to tell the `filter` method if the element `x` should be kept.

Comment: Now, if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting that the values of some of the columns might not be string? They might even be `null` or objects? Then you have to write a different comparison rule depending on what those values might be.
If the value are supposed to be string but your data source might mess with you, then you can try to wrap around that line with try-catch to avoid getting errors. Inside the `catch` block, you should also set `match = false` as well.